# Cant get users posts with facebook php sdk

Tags: php, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

When I try to get the users posts it just shows "Array ( [data] => Array ( ) )" (the profile shows and I can post to the wall). It works when I change "me" to a public page. The Login-link and user-info shows. Please help me, I don't get why it doesn't work!

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'facebook/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user)
{
    $url = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}
else
{
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

if ($user) {
  try {
      $pageFeed = $facebook->api('me' . '/feed');
      print_r($pageFeed);
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
?>

<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">LOGIN!</a>
<pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the read_stream permission on Login.
so you need to replace your getLoginUrl() call with the following.
You could also add more permissions separated by comma,
Ex: 'read_stream,publish_stream,etc...'

```
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'read_stream'));
```

Comment: Is there any way to only show what you see when you log into facebook?

Comment: Are you talking about the news feed?
There is no direct way to do this.
Take a look at this : http://goo.gl/5vIBv2

Comment: I found a way to do it, I used: 
$pageFeed = $facebook->api('me' . '/home');   instead of 
$pageFeed = $facebook->api('me' . '/feed');